# Gathering separate data into a single its object in R

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to use R to measure stock performance. The sample code is from here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-measure-stock-portfolio-performance-using-r-847c992195c2

In the section of code below we're trying to gather separate data into a single xts object. However, the resulting xts object would only list data from one date, rather than the entire date range that was specified. Sample code below:

```
 # IDX-BUMN20 Create Dataframe
 Index <- list(AAPL, NLY, FVRR)
 names(Index) <- IDXBUMN20
 Index <- lapply(Index, '[', i = 1, j = 6) # select only Adjusted close price
 Index <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, Index) #List to Dataframe
 names(Index) <- IDXBUMN20 # change colnames

 Index <- as.xts(Index)
```

Thank you very much for your help, novice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the data instead of `cbind`. Also `i = 1` keeps only 1 row, the link that you shared keeps it empty meaning selecting all the rows.

```
library(quantmod)
IDXBUMN20 = c('AAPL','NLY','FVRR')
getSymbols(IDXBUMN20)

Index <- list(AAPL, NLY, FVRR)
names(Index) <- IDXBUMN20
Index <- lapply(Index, '[', i =,j = 6) 
Index <- do.call(merge, Index) 
names(Index) <- IDXBUMN20
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak, this worked! Appreciate your help!